# ERROR/LocationManagerService(64): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

### I am create a simple web service.

but it generate an error like that shown below

```
09-25 20:42:56.732: ERROR/LocationManagerService(64): requestUpdates got exception:
09-25 20:42:56.732: ERROR/LocationManagerService(64): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=network
09-25 20:42:56.732: ERROR/LocationManagerService(64):     at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.requestLocationUpdatesLocked(LocationManagerService.java:861)
09-25 20:42:56.732: ERROR/LocationManagerService(64):     at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManagerService.java:831)
09-25 20:42:56.732: ERROR/LocationManagerService(64):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub.onTransact(ILocationManager.java:79)
09-25 20:42:56.732: ERROR/LocationManagerService(64):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:287)
09-25 20:42:56.732: ERROR/LocationManagerService(64):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

### java and XML code is shown below

```
package com.webview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebApplicationActivity extends Activity {
        WebView webView1,webView2;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        webView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView1.loadUrl("http://google.com");

//        webView2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
//        webView2.loadData("<html><head></head><body>Hello</body></html>", "text/html", null);

    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.webkit.WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"></android.webkit.WebView>
    <!-- <android.webkit.WebView android:id="@+id/webView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </android.webkit.WebView> -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show us the requestLocationUpdates() code

Comment: @Yashwanth Kumar : this is all application code , nothing remaining ..

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes from the location manager module trying to get the user current location from the cellular network, not from the code you posted.

Answer (score -1):

check you this code

```
   WebView  mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
   mWebView.setSaveFormData(false);
   mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

In the xml file. there should be webview id.

```
  android:id="@+id/webview"
```

It is also necessary to put this permission on AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In the HelloAndroid Activity, add this nested class:

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

}

Then towards the end of the onCreate(Bundle) method, set an instance of the HelloWebViewClient as the WebViewClient:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

if you want more about webView click this [link1](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html), [link2](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-webview.html) and [link3](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-webview-example-part-1)